# Error on TimeMachine (unable to backup)

Tags: backup, time-machine, mojave

Until the mid-april I was used Time Machine with no problem but now no backup is possible (Time  Machine starts, finds the drive, prepares the copy and stops). In the log I have found the following errors:

```
2019-04-30 14:22:38Error] Failed to mount APFS snapshot with name 'com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-04-10-174518' on volume '/' at mountpoint: '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/XXX/2019-04-10-174518/Macintosh HD', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2019-04-30 14:22:38Error] Failed to mount reference snapshot: com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-04-10-174518 source: Macintosh HD
```

Time Machine tries to find an old local snapshot which does not exist anymore (`sudo tmutil localsnapshot` gives me only the last one `Created local snapshot with date: 2019-04-30-143219`). On my drive I can see that the last snapshot (`sudo tmutil listbackups`) is `2019-04-10-181153`. So I don't understand what is  this issue.

My MBP is running on MacOs Mojave (10.14.2)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same problem today. I resolved my problem by rebooting to macOS Recovery (turn off your Mac and press ⌘+R during while pressing power button), and use disk utility to check(First Aid) my boot drive.

Comment: This hasn’t helped me, no errors found… [Clearing some space on the origin drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364826/90319) worked.